# MongoDB search a document and find value using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the following json data:

```
{ 
"name" : "Template1", 
"data" : {
    "columns" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Brand Size", 
            "record" : [
                {
                    "fname" : "column_search", 
                    "fields" : [
                        {
                            "name" : "column_search_form_search", 
                            "value" : "332"
                        }, 

                    ], 
                    "rules" : [
                        {
                            "rules_info_cond" : "if", 
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
        {
            "name" : "vendorArticleName", 
            "record" : [
                {
                    "fname" : "column_search", 

                    "rules" : [
                        {
                            "rules_info_cond" : "if", 
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
        {
            "name" : "Remarks", 
            "record" : [
                {
                    "fname" : "column_information_show", 

                    "rules" : [
                        [
                        ]
                    ]
},
```

}

I would like to get data->columns->name which have fname = 'column_information_show'
I was able to find using MongoDB but not able to find with PHP. Help me please!

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = json_decode($jsonData, true);

foreach($array['data']['columns'] as $value) {
    if($value['record']['fname'] == 'column_information_show'){
        return $value;
    }
}
```

This will loop through your json data and return the first column where the fname is equal to column_information_show. If there are multiple columns that you want to return you could add them to an array and then return it later.

Comment: What if it's an array data?

Comment: The first line of code that I posted simply decodes the json string to an array. So if you already have the array then you can skip the first line.